# Facebook PHP SDK - Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is my code:

login.php:

```
<?PHP
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '',
  'app_secret' => '',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email','public_profile']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://www.sportsector.bg/login-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

Here is my login-callback.php:

```
<?PHP
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '',
  'app_secret' => '',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);


try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();

echo 'Name: ' . $user['name'];
```

When i click the `Login with Facebook!` link i get redirected to Facebook where i have to click continue. After that i get back on my website receiving the following error:

```
Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token.
```

Can somebody tell me where is my mistake and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't retrieve the valid access token.

Change:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '',
  'app_secret' => '',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);


$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();  

try {  
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();  
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $accessToken );
  ....
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) { 
...
```

Have a look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0)

Comment: Now i receive the following error when i get back to my website: `Notice: Use of undefined constant accessToken - assumed 'accessToken' in /var/www/html/sportsector.bg/login-callback.php on line 19
Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token.`

Comment: Yepp sorry, forgot the `$` in `$accessToken`. mad an edit.

Comment: Now i am receiving the following error: `Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing.` Can you give me any advice about that ?

Answer (score 0):

**Error:

Facebook SDK returned an error: Access token was not returned from Graph.**

Only add Your call back URL in

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

to

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper('http://www.sportsector.bg/login-callback.php');

it's Working form me  ..

Comment: Does this really solve the original problem? Your error message looks different

Comment: Not worked for me, showing same error when adding redirect url.