# Facebook PHP SDK Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, package

I don't why I am getting this error.

My `appid` and `secret id` are all correct. Don't know what went wrong.

```
 <?PHP  
     $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '',
    'app_secret' => '',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
   ]);

 $data = [
  'message' => 'My awesome photo upload example.',
   'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel5-learning/public/image/share/'.$name),
     ];

    try {
   // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
   $response = $fb->post('/me/photos', $data, '{access-token}');
   } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
   echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
   exit;
  } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
  }


      $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

      echo 'Photo ID: ' . $graphNode['id'];


        ?>
```

It is showing this error:

> Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token.

Comment: hahah.. not screeming bro..its just typo error .. sorry for capslock

Comment: I am not your bro. Sorry for that.

Comment: sure dear...can you help me with my question

Comment: Where did you get the token? Have you tried from the graph Explorer? Usually this is from using a token for the wrong application

Comment: you didn't provide access token => {access-token} , you can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33867875