# How to get profile info from Facebook using Facebook-PHP-SDK

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am new to php and just downloaded Facebook php sdk and I am trying to write a very simple code to go to my personal Facebook retrieve the profile name and return it.  But I keep getting an error. Here is what I got so far.  I have already set up an account on Facebook Developers so I have an app id, app secret, and access token.

php file

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{}',
  'app_secret' => '{}',
  'persistent_data_handler' => 'memory',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.3',
  ]);

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();

echo 'Name: ' . $user['name'];
?>
```

Error Message

```
Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867590/facebook-php-sdk-graph-returned-an-error-invalid-oauth-access-token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works for me:

```
        $app_id = "your_app_id";
        $secret = "your_secret";
        $token = "your_token";
        $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => $app_id,
            'app_secret' => $secret,
            'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',
            'default_access_token' => $token, // optional
        ]);
```